# errors configuring prepacked wso2 identity server with wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I configured wso2 api manager with wso2 prepacked identity server 5.1.0. while trying to login into api publisher i got some errors

[image]

Comment: Did you check the ports are correct in configs?

Comment: Can you please provide the full stack trace. 'caused by' phrase would if there's such